# Telegram recurring message to one user

Tags: python, telegram, recurring

I need to send two specific recurring messages to a user in telegram .

The first message is followed by the second after some seconds .

It will be the same two messages every 10 mn ,everyday !

Example :

RecurringMessage1 :
I AM READY

then after some seconds comes the second one :

RecurringMessage2 :
YOU CAN SEND NOW

This would be repeated every 10 mn every day and so on .

The receiver is a bot on telegram that has a @username only .
( i dont have the skills to get his chat id , and restricted to include him in any group ) .

Any help is highly appreciated .

Tried using scheduled messages feature of telegram , it works but it is completely unpractical to use it due to the large number of recurring messages .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `telethon` module to get the chat id of the bot while it's reading all your current incoming messages.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
```

Otherwise if you remove the '@' from the bot's name e.g. @MyBot, you should be able to use https://t.me/MyBot as an alternative.

Comment: The method https://t.me/MyBot    ( the bot username instead of MyBot)  did not give any result . It just took me to the bot on telegram ….( First method no time yet to check )